# How to disable autofill in webkit-based browser application on ios

Tags: ios, webkit, autofill

I want to build a private browsing feature in webkit-based application on iOS, it doesn't save autofill data, e.g. you open facebook, login and then close the page,  it won't login automatically when you open facebook again.

So I want to disable cookies save, but I fail to find useful api.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application has its own "`cookie jar`" in the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` container. 
You could make a function inside the html of the WebView, that cleans the cookies.
Several methods are available for filtering and manipulation, this links can help you:
[NSHTTPCookie](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/index.html)
[NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html)